# Windows 7, wxpython, unknown font weight

Tags: windows-7, encoding, fonts, wxpython

I'm kind of new at this:

My app works great in Linux, where I developed it. I'm trying to port it to win7 before making it an exe (the school psych wants to use it on her computer). One of the functions of the app is to change the font size in response to an event (in this case, the user presses a button).

Here's the code:

```
if countfinal == 1:
        on_start = time.time()
        ot.append(on_start) 
        self.welcome.SetLabel("Timing On Task Event") 
        self.label_directions.SetLabel("Timing On Task Event")
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)  
        on.append(1)
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.DEFAULT, wx.FONTENCODING_SYSTEM) 
        self.label_directions.SetFont(font)  
        self.save_quit.Enable(False)
```

Windows 7 throws up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "time.py", line 131, in time_event
font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.DEFAULT, wx.FONTENCODING_SYSTEM)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_gdi.py", line 2081,           in       __init__
_gdi_.Font_swiginit(self,_gdi_.new_Font(*args, **kwargs))
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "wxAssertFailure" failed at ..\..\src     \msw\font.cpp(560) in wxNativeFontInfo::Se
tWeight(): unknown font weight
```

I've been reading that it has something to do with Windows not using UTF-8. That's nice, but it doesn't help me.

How do I tell wx to use the font encoding Windows 7 recognizes? Could someone be so kind as to provide me with a code example that does this? The documentation is a little too cryptic for me; I'm still at that struggling neophyte stage with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out where my mistake was on this one. I was doing two things wrong:

1. I was misreading the error code. The error code referred to "weight" and not "size." The whole utf-8 thing really was a rabbit hole to nowhere.
2. I was putting things in the wrong order. [Mike Driscoll's tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/) makes it clear with this example:

   font = wx.Font(size, families[family], styles[style],
                                  weights[weight])

that wx is picky about the order of attributes. It goes size, family, style, weight. I had them out of order. I think I was also using the wrong wx attributes. It seems that some tutorials will include wx.DEFAULT rather than wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT. That's wickedly confusing to a new programmer. Is it really that hard to just write out the first part of the tag? Especially in a tutorial?

Here's the code that works:

```
if countfinal == 1

        size = 18 
        font = wx.Font(size, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL) 
        self.label_directions.SetFont(font)
```

Special thanks to Mike Driscoll for posting an answer and for writing that tutorial!

Cheers!

Comment: I'm guessing wx.DEFAULT and wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT are mapped to the same value and can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll, I think you're right about them being mapped to the same value. What makes it difficult for me as a learner is that there are two different conventions for approaching the same function, with no apparent/significant advantage or disadvantage to either approach other than brevity. I like the FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT convention because it makes it clearer to a human reader what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I agree that explicit usually trumps implicit, especially when learning something new.

Comment: The id for wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT and wx.DEFAULT are the same, so I think they would work interchangeably. I also think it's a little weird to accept my answer, then write your own answer based on mine so you can accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article about fonts on my [blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/). I just tried the code and added an 18 pt font to the "sizes" list and it worked fine. Maybe you could try it on your computer and see if it works there too? If it does, then you'll want to see where your code differs from mine.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. I'm not using a dictionary for the fonts in my code, but I did figure out from your tutorial what I was doing wrong. I will include it in answer below.